# Check the version of Apache web server on Suse Linux ES 12

Tags: apache, apache2

does anyone know how I could check the version of apache2 web server on Linux Suse Enterprise Server 12?
I tried **httpd -v** and **apache2 -v** but those options don't work on this version of linux.
I would like to update the apache server, but unfortunately I have not worked with this version of linux until now.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the installed rpm package by

```
rpm -q -i apache2
```

and also check the changelog of the package by

```
rpm -q --changelog apache2
```

because current security fixes are backported to the originally released version.